# How to align all of these slashes at the EOL

Tags: vim

I am trying to align all of the slashes at the end of these lines (there are about 800 more lines) in a neat way. Preferably I'd like all of the slashes at column 80 (I am using vim). Any one have a solution? Here is an example:

```
#define  TAILQ_INIT(head) do {               \
   (head)->tqh_first = NULL;           \
   (head)->tqh_last = &(head)->tqh_first;         \
} while (0)
```

Comment: Hi there. Instead of using a picture link it would be easier if you added as a code formatted section.

Comment: @drclaw how did you do that? I was trying but could not figure it out!

Comment: @tgfsoftware this gives both the reasons why code as image is frowned upon AND how to go about fixing it.

https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: There is a very handy plugin for this if you find yourself frequently trying to align code, called vim-easy-align. https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align

Comment: @tgfsoftware I've retracted my downvote for the code image, and given you an upvote. Thanks for sharing it as a codeblock.

Answer (score 2):

This command will help, if your codes/text:

- use `spaces` instead of `Tab`,
- length of text before `\s*\\$` <80

  ```
  %s/\v(.{-})\s*\\$/\=submatch(1).repeat(' ',79-len(submatch(1))).'\'
  ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked great. However since I used tabs instead of spaces, I had to convert my existing tabs to spaces. I did this with: :set tabstop=3 shiftwidth=3 expandtab and then :retab and then I entered your command. Please feel free to reformat this comment, I am new and still learning how to make things pretty

Answer (score 0):

If your text width is set to 80:

```
set textwidth=80
```

You can use the following function as base:

```
function! RightAlign(char)
    if strlen(a:char) > 1
        return
    endif
    let l:linelength = strlen(getline('.'))
    right
    let l:spaces = strlen(getline('.')) - l:linelength
    execute "normal 0|d" . l:spaces . "l"
    execute "normal f" . a:char
    normal P
end
funccommand -range -nargs=1 RightAlign <line1>,<line2>call RightAlign(<args>)
```

Use it as follow on the line you want to align:

```
:RightAlign('/')
```

The argument is the first character you want to align on the right.

It can be called in a range:

```
:'<,'>RightAlign '/'
:%RightAlign '/'
```

If the argument you pass is longer than 1 char, the function will just return.

Also, it works better if you use spaces and not tabs (It would need some modifications for that too).